# Multiple inheretince in classes with functions that have the same name

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

If you have one class using multiple inheritance using two classes with the same name for a function, which function takes priority? From what I found the function coming first in the class declaration takes priority. Is there a better way to call a function from the class listed second than what I have now?

```
class test():
    number = 10
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.something = z
    def printnumber(self):
        print(self.number)
class trial():
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def printnumber(self):
        print(self.c)
class check(test, trial):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c,x,y,z):
        trial.__init__(self ,a, b, c)
        test.__init__(self, x,y,z)
    def printnumber(self):
        return trial.printnumber(self)
```

Also, just curious, are there any other times in multiple inheretince or classes in general where the order that you list the classes in the class header matters?

Comment: Rename one of the functions?

Answer (score -1):

The search order is basically depth-first, left-to-right.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

However, because of the confusion it induces, it is generally bad form to write code like this.  Multiple inheritance (beyond the very useful concept of a mix-in) is a dangerous practice that rarely pays in the long term.